# C++ using string_view in constexpr if

Tags: c++, constexpr, string-view

I want to compare string views at compile time like this:

```cpp
constexpr bool isMatch(const string_view str) {
  if constexpr (str == "firstMatch"sv) {
      return true;
  } else if constexpr (str == "secondMatch"sv) {
     return true;
  }
  // ....
}
```

And the function is called like this:

```cpp
isMatch("something"sv);
```

Which is obviously constant because it's right in the code.

But the compiler says that the expression inside the if constexpr 'did not evaluate to a constant'. But operator== of a string_view is constexpr. A solution would be to declare the parameter constexpr but it's not possible.

So how can I have a constexpr function that checks for these kind of matches at compile time?

Comment: Remove `constexpr` from `if constexpr`.

Comment: Your `str` parameter is not constexpr therefore the expression `str == "abc"` is not constexpr. Note that `constexpr` functions **can** be called at runtime, which means `str` could be a runtime known value, so you cannot always guarantee that the value is known at compile time.

Comment: @KamilCuk If I remove constexpr, I have no guarantee that the code will be executed at compile time, and I could not make a `static_assert(false "invalid str")` at the end to make sure that the str is valid.

Comment: If the function is called at compile time, the body obviously is also executed at compile time, no matter if the `if` is `constexpr` or not. `if constexpr` is mostly useful if you have to deal with different types and template arguments.

Comment: That's not what `constexpr` does. To have it called at compile time for sure, you can do like `constexpr bool var = isMatch(..)`. `and I could not make a` Because you can't - function arguments can change, they are not constexpr.

Comment: If you want to ensure that your code runs at compile time, and you have C++20, you can make the function `consteval` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how can I have a constexpr function that checks for these kind of matches

Just remove the `constexpr` from `if`s.

```
constexpr bool isMatch(const string_view str) {
  if (str == "firstMatch"sv) {
      return true;
  } else if (str == "secondMatch"sv) {
     return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

`std::string_view::operator==` is `constexpr` so all is fine.

> at compile time?

*Call* your function in compile time context. Like:

```
#include <array>
#include <cassert>
#include <string_view>
using namespace std::literals;

constexpr bool isMatch(const std::string_view str) {
  if (str == "firstMatch"sv) {
      return true;
  } else if (str == "secondMatch"sv) {
     return true;
  }
  return false;
}

int main() {
    std::array<int, isMatch("secondMatch"sv)> arr;
    static_assert(isMatch("firstMatch"sv));
    constexpr bool var = isMatch("No match for you!"sv);
}
```

In C++20 you can make sure that your function is called only at compile time with `consteval`.

Comment: Ok it looks fine but can I have compile time execution if I have a function `foo(bool match)` and call it like `foo(isMatch("test"sv))`? Does the `isMatch` is compile time in this case? Because I could define a `constexpr bool match = isMatch("test"sv)` and then call `foo(match)` but it's too much annoyance, I would like to pass it directly

Comment: You have to split "guaranteed to be compile time" vs "is compile time". Theoretically, when you write `foo(1 ==1)` there is no _guarantee_ that `1 == 1` comparison will be executed at compile time. But practically, any compiler will optimize it. It's similar with `constexpr` function. A `constexpr` function _may be_ executed on runtime. But any self-respecting compiler will optimize it. So to answer `foo(isMatch("test"sv))? Does the isMatch is compile time` there is no guarantee for that, but it will be. If you want that guarantee, communicate that intention to the compiler explicitly.